# Combining variables in a table

Tags: powershell

I am trying to combine two variables each containing a list of values:

```
cls
    $Sites = Get-ADReplicationSite -Filter *
    $Subnets = Get-ADReplicationSubnet -Filter * 

    $a = New-Object PSObject
      $a | add-member Noteproperty "Site" $Sites.Name
      $a | add-member Noteproperty "Subnet" $Subnets.Name
    $a | format-table
```

My output looks like this:

```
Site                                     Subnet                                 
----                                     ------                                 
{Default-First-Site-Name, SITE1, SI... {10.0.0.0/24, 20.0.0.0/24, 30.0.0.0/...
```

As the above does not result in a clear table I wonder where I went wrong. Preferably I would combine these two variables into a .csv file. However I am not sure on how I would give each list a Header before piping it to the `Export-CSV` cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the number of sites is equal to the number of subnets, try this:

```
$sites | Foreach {$i=0}{new-object pscustomobject -prop @{Site=$_;Subnet=$subnets[$i]}; $i++} | Format-Table
```

Comment: When running this I get the following error: Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal. I'd try to fix it myself but I dont really understand the way it works, so yeah.

Comment: Try again.  It was missing a closing } on the hashtable.

Comment: Alright, that works perfect. Could you please explain how and why this works?

Comment: You can more easily create a custom PowerShell object using `new-object pscustomobject -Propert @{.. hashtable ..}`.  The `foreach` command takes potentially three scriptblocks. The first, when there is more than one, is the `begin` scriptblock.  It happens once at the startup of the pipeline.  That is used to set the index variable `$i` to 0.  The next scriptblock executes for once for every object in the pipeline.  We create the custom object and increment the index variable.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know that foreach took multiple scriptblocks. Makes the code alot cleaner. Cheers.